# How to merge rows that contain NAs into one in r?

Tags: r, merge

Here is my data:

```
data<-structure(c(1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 9), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2"), NULL), .Names = c("1", "2", NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I have NAs for each row, but the rows correspond each other (if there is NA for a row, there is a value on the other row in the same columns)

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
1    1    2   NA
2   NA   NA    9
```

Here is the desired output:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
1    1    2    9



structure(c(1, 2, 9), .Dim = c(1L, 3L), .Dimnames = list("1", 
    NULL))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the strict assumption that the number of non-`NA` values is the same for each column, one can do

```r
t(apply(data, 2, na.omit))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    9
```

The need for `t(..)` is distinct for this example, since `apply` *here* will auto-simplify to a vector, not to an array. If your data produces more than two non-`NA` values, then you can do without `t(..)`:

```r
data <- rbind(data, data)
data
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# 1    1    2   NA
# 2   NA   NA    9
# 1    1    2   NA
# 2   NA   NA    9
apply(data, 2, na.omit)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    9
# [2,]    1    2    9
```

---

@akrun made a great point: if a column is all `NA`, this will fail. Here's a slight fix for that:

```r
apply(data, 2, function(z) { out <- na.omit(z); if (!length(out)) NA else out; })
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    9
# [2,]    1    2    9
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be also good to add a condition to check `if` `all` the values in a column are `NA`, then return `NA` or `else` remove the `NA`

```
sapply(asplit(data, 2), function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_real_
         else x[complete.cases(x)])
```

Comment: @r2evans It also depends on the number of non-NA elements which can return a `list` column if the number of NAs are not same across.  thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's why I started my answer with *"strict assumption"*. There are a lot of things that can go wrong with this type of problem, and I didn't want to go down too many rabbit-holes. Based on the OP description, I'm not convinced that an all-`NA` column is likely, but it's easy enough to guard against.

Answer (score 1):

Try `colSums`

```
> t(colSums(data, na.rm = TRUE))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    9
```